# Plot Through Struct Array Matlab - The Intresting Case

Tags: matlab, recursion, struct, field, matlab-figure

Say I have a struct of the form:

```
firstrun.(char(patient(ldy,1))).(char(dypatient(llc,1))).(char(lcpatient(mps,1))).MaxCount;
```

The struct variable then has patient of length i, the dypatient also has a length j and so on. This allows us to have a tree so that we can pick a from the field patient and pick other fields related to that patient.

Now at the end of the line or tha last field where all the values are stored I have a field which holds a single value. MaxCount. as in the code below.

For each patient there is a first day or day a, hospital ID or location. In the location filed I have a MaxCount.

On a second day or day b for example I have the same hospital ID or location but with a different MaxCount.

I would like to have a plot of a max count over the number days, bearing in mind these are singular values. For example:

```
firstrun.patientID.dayID_1.hospID_3.MaxCount is only 39
firstrun.patientID.dayID_2.hospID_3.MaxCount is only 22
.
.
.
firstrun.patientID.dayID_i.hospID_j.MaxCount is only 2

The vector to plot is then [39, 22, ...., n]
```

So I have different plots for the number of visits to each hospitalID or location over several days.

```
%% load file

load('/Users/dave/Desktop/firstrun.mat')

   if exist('firstrun','var')==1

        patient = fieldnames(firstrun);
        for ldy = 1:length(patient);
            dypatient = fieldnames(firstrun.(char(patient(ldy,1))));
            for llc = 1:length(dypatient);
                lcpatient = fieldnames(firstrun.(char(patient(ldy,1))).(char(dypatient(llc,1))));
                for mps = 1:length(lcpatient);
                    pspatient = fieldnames(firstrun.(char(patient(ldy,1))).(char(dypatient(llc,1))).(char(lcpatient(mps,1))));
                    MaxCount = firstrun.(char(patient(ldy,1))).(char(dypatient(llc,1))).(char(lcpatient(mps,1))).MaxCount;





                end

            end

        end

           else

       disp('Variable does not exist') 

   end
```

How can I cycle through the locations for each day for the same patient, grouping the same locations together and plot how the visits to each location changes?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Rigusorio, would be helpful to see your "firstrun.mat", can you upload somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below does it

```
%% load file

load('/Users/dave/Desktop/TrialRun.mat’)

if exist('variablestruct','var')==1

        patient = fieldnames(Patesyap);
        for ldy = 1:length(patient);
            dypatient = fieldnames(DataSynapto.(char(patient(ldy,1))));
            for llc = 1:length(dypatient);
                lcpatient = fieldnames(DataSynapto.(char(patient(ldy,1))).(char(dypatient(llc,1))));
                for mps = 1:length(lcpatient);
                    pspatient = fieldnames(DataSynapto.(char(patient(ldy,1))).(char(dypatient(llc,1))).(char(lcpatient(mps,1))));
                    MaxCount = DataSynapto.(char(patient(ldy,1))).(char(dypatient(llc,1))).(char(lcpatient(mps,1))).MaxCount;
                    TemppatientID = patient(ldy,1);
                    PlotpatientLoc.(char(TemppatientID))(llc,1).(char(lcpatient(mps,1)))=MaxCount;                                 
                end

            end

        end
   else

       disp('variablestruct does not exist') 

end



if exist('PlotpatientLoc','var')==1

    PlotHold = fieldnames(PlotpatientLoc);

    for patientIDPlot = 1:length(PlotHold);

        mpatient = fieldnames(PlotpatientLoc.(char(PlotHold(patientIDPlot,1))));

        for locloos = 1:length(mpatient);

            plot((1:max(size([PlotpatientLoc.(char(PlotHold(patientIDPlot,1))).(char(mpatient(locloos,1)))]))),...
                [PlotpatientLoc.(char(PlotHold(patientIDPlot,1))).(char(mpatient(locloos,1)))])
            hold on

        end

    end

else 
    disp('Plot Variable Do not exist') 
end
```